# Copy Check Box to Every 5th Cell with Command Button

Tags: excel, checkbox, copy-paste, vba

I have an issue which i can't solve.I wrote this code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Sheets("sheet2").OLEObjects("CheckBox1").Copy

Sheets("sheet3").Range("V7").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

This code copy a checkbox from (sheet 2) to (sheet 3) starting from V7 cell. Now I want the next time I press the command button to paste the data to cell V12,next time to V17 etc. My vba knowledge is not very good as you can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will see how many checkboxes are already in the sheet you are pasting to and add 5 rows for each check box, then paste five rows under the last one.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

' copy checkbox
Sheets("sheet2").OLEObjects("CheckBox1").Copy

Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = Sheets("Sheet3")

Dim cb As OLEObject, i As Integer

'determine how many boxes are already there and get count of cell to paste to
i = 7
For Each cb In wks.OLEObjects
    If InStr(1, cb.Name, "CheckBox") Then i = i + 5
Next

'paste new checkbox
Sheets("sheet3").Range("V" & i).PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what data you got between in Sheet(3).Range("V7") and Sheet(3).Range("V12")

but juste before you're PasteSpecial, you shoud keep track where was the last time you paste data in Sheets("sheets3") in a specific cell in Sheet("sheets3"), in exemple : Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1")

Then you'll be able to pastespecial to this cell 5 row under like this :

Sheets("sheet3").Range(Sheets("Sheets3").Range("A1").Offset(5,0)).PasteSpecial
right after that you update the Sheets("Sheets3").Range("A1") = Sheets("sheet3").Range(Sheets("Sheets3").Range("A1").Offset(5,0)).Address

So this should do the work :

```
    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim oWsSource as Worksheet
    Dim oWsDestination as Worksheet
    Set oWsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("Sheets3")
    Set oWsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("Sheets2")
        'Do the copy
        oWsSource.OLEObjects("CheckBox1").Copy
        oWsDestination.Range(oWsDestination.Range("A1").Value).Offset(5,0)).PasteSpecial
        oWsDestination.Range("A1").Value = oWsDestination.Range(oWsDestination.Range("A1").Value).Offset(5, 0)).Address

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a global variable. These must be at the top of your sheet, module, or form code above all subs and functions.

Then use that as the row number in your range. `Range("V" & lRow)`

```
Private lRow As Long

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    'Let's check if this is the first time the button has been used.
    If lRow = 0 then
        lRow = 7
    Else
        'Increment the row from the one we wrote to last time.
        lRow = lRow + 5
    End If

    'Do the copy
    Sheets("sheet2").OLEObjects("CheckBox1").Copy
    Sheets("sheet3").Range("V" & lRow).PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Comment: I could be wrong about this, but if the workbook is closed and then reopened `lRow` will reset to 0 and thus the counter will start over and paste checkboxes on top of each other if some already exist.

Comment: That is true.  OP doesn't state it needs to start at the bottom each time the workbook is opened. If so he can find the last and use that.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers put the first checkbox but the next one put it again to the same cell as before.I don't know if its matter but I use excel 2010.